# How to scroll to specified item in PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, scroll, preference

My app has a global preference, which contains settings for all the activities. If I click setting in different activity, I want the `PreferenceActivity` automatically scroll to the setting section of that activity.

I try to use `getListView().setSelection(i)` to realize this function. However, in `onCreate()` and `onResume()`, `getListView()` hasn't been initialized.

How can I know when the `ListView` of `PreferecneActivity` will be initialized, or is there any other way to realize this function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in `onResume()`, `getView().post(new Runnable());`

Because the view has to dispatch after created. And do your work in runnable is ok.